# js math function for y√(x)?

Tags: javascript, math

<sup>3</sup>√(9) =  2.0800838231, or <sup>Y</sup>√x

**is there any `Math` function in vanilla js for calculation above the formula ?**

Comment: can you properly format the example

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```js
console.log(Math.pow(9, 1/3)); // replace "3" with the root
// "9" with your number
```

Comment: please consider giving some explanation and do not dump code!

Comment: this is pretty self explanatory he's just raising the number to 1/y

Answer (score 1):

This is what i think will work:

```js
document.write(Math.pow(9, 1 / 3));
```

**pow** raises the second argument to the power of first argument.

Now from basic math we know `3√(9) = (9)^(1/3)`

Answer (score 0):

The Math.cbrt() function returns the cube root of a number.

Math.cbrt(x) returns y where x is a number and y * y * y = x.

For example, cube root of 27 = 3 , cube root of 8 = 2.

Math.cbrt(27) = 3.
Here x = 27 and y = 3. So, y * y * y =  x. So, 3 * 3 * 3 = 27.

```js
console.log(Math.cbrt(8),2);
console.log(Math.cbrt(27),3);
console.log(Math.cbrt(9),2.080083823051904);
```